# PyTorch rand(device) vs rand.to(device)

Tags: python, pytorch

Pytorch newbie here: wondering why these two produce different results? My speculation is one computes rand in CPU and send tensor to GPU while one sends tensor to GPU and computes rand in GPU.

```
torch.manual_seed(1234)
print(torch.rand(size=(2,3),device=device))
print(torch.rand(size=(2,3),device=device))
"""
tensor([[0.1272, 0.8167, 0.5440],
        [0.6601, 0.2721, 0.9737]], device='cuda:0')
tensor([[0.6208, 0.0276, 0.3255],
        [0.1114, 0.6812, 0.3608]], device='cuda:0')
"""
```

```
torch.manual_seed(1234)
print(torch.rand(size=(2,3)).to(device))
print(torch.rand(size=(2,3)).to(device))
"""
tensor([[0.0290, 0.4019, 0.2598],
        [0.3666, 0.0583, 0.7006]], device='cuda:0')
tensor([[0.0518, 0.4681, 0.6738],
        [0.3315, 0.7837, 0.5631]], device='cuda:0')
"""
```

Comment: When you use `rand().to(device)`, you're initializing the variable first on CPU, then sending it to the GPU (assuming device = GPU). When you use `rand(device)`, it is initialized on the GPU without creating it on CPU first.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

Cross-device reproducibility of random numbers is currently not possible in PyTorch.

### Long answer

As already noted in Djinn's comment, indeed you directly produce the random numbers on the GPU in your first code sample (`rand(..., device=device)`), while you produce the random numbers on the CPU, then move them to the GPU, in your second code sample (`rand(...).to(device)`) – assuming that your default device is the CPU and that your `device` is a GPU device, of course. So your speculation was pretty much correct.

The underlying problem as to why the numbers differ is that in PyTorch, using the same random seed on different devices will generally *not* produce the same sequence of random numbers. This is [documented here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html) (quote: *results may not be reproducible between CPU and GPU executions, even when using identical seeds*). An issue that aims at changing this, so that the behavior would be as you probably expected, has been [opened in PyTorch's GitHub repo](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/84234) in 2022 (and has since remained open).

At present, if you want to ensure the same sequence of random numbers, the only option that I see seems to be the following: always create your random numbers on the same device (probably it's best to always create them on the CPU as it should always be available, while a GPU is not necessarily available) and then move them to the desired device for processing (e.g. to the GPU if it is available).